# how to use several categorical columns for pandas scatter color param

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to make a scatter plot using pandas and several categorical variables for the colormap. For one column, the `c` arg works well, but if I want the product of two or more columns I don't know what to do. I have tried using a list but did not work, see MWE below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.clf()
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.random((10, 4)),
        columns=["x", "y", "a", "b"],
    )
    .assign(
        a=lambda df: pd.Categorical(np.where(df.a > 0.5, "A", "AA")),
        b=lambda df: pd.Categorical(np.where(df.b > 0.5, "B", "BB")),
    )
)

df.plot.scatter("x", "y", c="a")
# OK
df.plot.scatter("x", "y", c=["a", "b"])
# ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not ['a', 'b']
```

#### EDIT

creating a new column concatenating `a` and `b` should not be a solution

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, with Altair, you can do it like this. Note the interactive tooltip if you hover over a point which will show the categories for both columns A and B.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt


df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.random((10, 4)),
        columns=["x", "y", "a", "b"],
    )
    .assign(
        a=lambda df: pd.Categorical(np.where(df.a > 0.5, "A", "AA")),
        b=lambda df: pd.Categorical(np.where(df.b > 0.5, "B", "BB")),
    )
)

chrta = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle(opacity=0.9).encode(
    x="x",
    y="y",
    color=alt.Color("a", legend=None, scale=alt.Scale(scheme='category10'))
)

chrtb = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle(opacity=0.6).encode(
    x="x",
    y="y",
    color=alt.Color("b", legend=None, scale=alt.Scale(scheme='category20')),
    tooltip=["a", "b"]
)

chrta + chrtb
```

Comment: +1 for altair though I am still missing something as easy as `c=interaction('a', 'b')` as done un ggplot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the matplotlib alpha option to reduce the opacity of the colors from column a so that when you plot column b over it the color will be a combination of the 2 colors.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.clf()
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.random((10, 4)),
        columns=["x", "y", "a", "b"],
    )
    .assign(
        a=lambda df: pd.Categorical(np.where(df.a > 0.5, "A", "AA")),
        b=lambda df: pd.Categorical(np.where(df.b > 0.5, "B", "BB")),
    )
)

colors = [None] * 2

colors[0] = {'AA':'red', 'A':'blue'}
colors[1] = {'BB':'green', 'B':'black'}

cat_cols = ['a', 'b']

for m in range(0,2):
    plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], c=df[cat_cols[m]].map(colors[m]), alpha=0.2)
```